# moveTaskToBack with wallpaper flags causes black flicker on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an activity that is set to show the device wallpaper, i.e: 
in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
>
```

In the Activity's `OnCreate`:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WALLPAPER)
```

When I call

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

The activity disappears as expected, so far so good.
However, when running this on Jelly Bean, such as a Galaxy S3 running 4.1.1, there is a very visible black flicker during the transition right after moveTaskToBack. The flicker only happens if the Home activity is right below my activity.

The issue is fully reproducible with a simple activity set up as I described.

The flicker does not happen if I use `finish()` instead, but using finish is not an option. It also doesn't happen on an S3 running ICS.

I suspect this might be related to some refresh of the wallpaper, or maybe something to do with changes in Project Butter, but I'm out of ideas.

How do I get rid of this flicker while still being able to see the device wallpaper, and without destroying the activity when I move it out of view?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a simlar problem just now related to moveTaskToBack(true). The behavior of this API is clearly different on JellyBean vs ICS, however I can't find any documentation that helps.